# Clean everything after start till to the end point

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

Want to clean everything after one start point till the end one

Example:

```
    <!--
        <group>
                <name>Octopus</name>
                <inventory>
                        <inventoryName>octopus</inventoryName>
                        <decoder>DFFDD</decoder>
                        <command>cat /etc/hosts</command>
                </inventory>
        </group>
 -->
```

Where `<!--` is the start point and `-->` is the end point sometimes content is multiple lines to the end point. 
Everything which is in those tags I want to be deleted.

I try to start some things with sed like:

`sed 's/^<\!--//g'` but not sure how to continue after it to catch all and to be cleaned when saw the end tag.

Comment: Can you ensure than: every `<!-- some -->` is only in one line? Or here are multiline comments too. Can you ensure than here isn't nested comments like `<!-- some <!-- another --> one -->` ?

Comment: If you want to parse HTML, use an HTML parser, not regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, sometime is multiline @jm666

Comment: @jm666 You can't have nested comments like that in valid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non greedy substitution regex where `.` is matching even newlines,

```
$string =~ s|<!-- .*? -->||xsg;
```

Comment: How to use that is for sed or something else ?!

Comment: @KalinBorisov, that is perl syntax

Comment: @glenn jackman Aham, but how to use it to change everything for example in one file. I try with `perl "$string =~ s|<!-- .*? -->||xsg;"`

Comment: It can be as short as `perl -0777 -lpe 's|<!-- .*? -->||xsg' file.xml` to make changes on the whole file in one shot. Use the `-i` switch to save changes back into the file.

Answer (score 3):

If I get what you want to do, you want to remove comments. Right?

What about something like this?

```
<!--
     blah blah blah -->
```

Or

```
<!-- blah blah blah -->
```

Or

```
<!-- blah blah blah
-->
```

Or even this?

```
 <foo><bar> <!-- <fubar>blah blah</fubar> --> </bar></foo>
```

You cannot use regular expressions on XML because XML is just too complex. There are a lot of Perl libraries that parse XML data, and you should use these.

Although it isn't preferred anymore, [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm) may do exactly what you want with an absolute minimum of fuss. `XML::Simple` can rebuild your XML file into a ***compatible*** version. The entities might not match exactly, but it will be compatible with what your old structure. And, XML::Simple removes comments.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml_struct_ref = XMLin( $xml_file );
my $xml_file_output = XMLout ( $xml_struct_ref );
```

And then, you simply write `$xml_file_output` to your new XML file. All comments removed!

Comment: IMHO, this the ****only**** correct solution - at least from the current answers. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r '/<!--/,/-->/{//!d;s/(.*<!--).*/\1/;s/.*(-->.*)/\1/}' file
```

---

Session protocol:

```
    $ cat file
    test line #1
    <AXXX> <!--  <BXXX>
        <group>
            <name>Octopus</name>
            <inventory>
                <inventoryName>octopus</inventoryName>
                <decoder>DFFDD</decoder>
                <command>cat /etc/hosts</command>
            </inventory>
        </group>
    <CXXX> --> <DXXX>
    test line 12
$ sed -r '/<!--/,/-->/{//!d;s/(.*<!--).*/\1/;s/.*(-->.*)/\1/}' file
test line #1
<AXXX> <!--
--> <DXXX>
test line 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];

open FILE, "<$filename" or die $!;
local $/;
my $text = <FILE>;
close FILE;

$text =~ s/<!--[\s\S]*?-->//g;

open FILE, ">$filename" or die $!;
print FILE $text;
close FILE;
```

You need `[\s\S]*?` (alternatively `(.|\n)`) for the shortest match of any character, including newlines. `.` alone wouldn't work for multiline strings, because it matches any character except newlines.

Run the script like this:

```
./script.pl /path/to/your.file
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aParser) you can find an similar snippet:

```
perl -0777 -MHTML::Parser -nE 'HTML::Parser->new(default_h=>[sub{print shift},"text"],comment_h=>[""])->parse($_)||die $!' < file.html >decommented.html
```

tested on the next html:

```
simple
<!-- this is an comment -->
multi
<!--
this is an
multiline comment
-->
stupid
<img src="copen.jpg" alt='image of open tag <!--'>
<img src="cclose.jpg" alt='image of closing tag -->'>
js
<script>
alert("<!-- here -->");
</script>
end
```

and prints:

```
simple

multi

stupid
<img src="copen.jpg" alt='image of open tag <!--'> <img src="cclose.jpg" alt='image of closing tag -->'>
js
<script>
alert("<!-- here -->");
</script>
```

Comment: AHHHHH.... I'm not reloaded the page before entered the answer. I assumed than you have `HTML` - you added the `xml` example later. I'm not really sure how will work this for XML - should, but i'm not 100% sure. Sry for confusion. But, one thing: you SHOULD use a parser. It is impossible to do with regexes correctly. See my example html.